# Receive data from multiple tables [Nodejs,MySQL]

Tags: mysql, node.js

What do I need to do to get data from multiple tables?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host : '',
user : '',
password : '',
database : ''
});

connection.connect(function(){
console.log("MySQL Database is Connected");
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/js'));

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.get('/',function(req,res){

res.render('index.html');

});

app.get('/load',function(req,res){

connection.query("select * from terms WHERE status = 1",
function(err,rows,fields){
if(err) throw err;
res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
});

});

app.listen(7001,function(){
console.log("App is started at PORT 7001");
});
```

With this I can only get data from the `terms` table. But I need to get data from the `impTerms` table.
How do I get this?

Thank you

Comment: On sql level you either join them or use a union, on js level just execute another select statement. Your question is unclear because you do not describe what you want to do with the data.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use sql `join` in query , has nothing to do with node js.

```
con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var sql = "SELECT terms.id, terms.name  FROM terms JOIN impTerms ON impTerms.id= terms.id and terms.status=1";
      con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do,

1. Passing two sql queries to connection

```
Var sqlQuery = "select * from terms WHERE status = 1;select * from impTerms";

connection.query(sqlQuery,
function(err,rows,fields){
if(err) throw err;
res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
});
```

Output:

```
[ 
[],  // array of object for terms
[]  // array of object for impTerms
]
```

2. Changing select query

```
Var sqlQuery = "select a.*, b.*  from a.terms, b.impTerms";

connection.query(sqlQuery,
function(err,rows,fields){
if(err) throw err;
res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
});
```

Comment: I've correctly re-created the question. If you want; you can check [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56197586/receive-data-from-multiple-tables-angular-nodejs-mysql)

Comment: There is a third option. You can use stored procedure and return more than one table at once.